# Xlsxwriter - Trouble formatting pandas dataframe cells using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have an excel sheet which came from a pandas dataframe. I then use Xlsxwriter to add formulas, new columns and formatting. The problem is I only seem to be able format what I've written using xlsxwriter and nothing that came from the dataframe. So what I get is something like this [half formatted table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqa0e.png)

As you can see from the image the two columns from the dataframe remain untouched. They must have some kind of default formatting that is overriding mine.

Since I don't know how to convert a worksheet back into to a dataframe the code below is obviously completely wrong but it's just to give an idea of what I'm looking for.

```
export = "files/sharepointExtract.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(export)# df = dataframe

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('files/new_report-%s.xlsx' % (date.today()), engine = 'xlsxwriter')
workbook = writer.book

# Code to make the header red, this works fine because 
# it's written in xlsxwriter using write.row()

colour_format = workbook.add_format()
colour_format.set_bg_color('#640000')
colour_format.set_font_color('white')
worksheet.set_row(0, 15, colour_format)

table_body_format = workbook.add_format()
table_body_format.set_bg_color('blue')

for row in worksheet.rows:
  row.set_row(0,15, table_body_format)
```

This code gives an Attribute error but even without the for loop we just get what can be seen in the image.

Comment: Can you include the part of the code where you write the data as well, so we can see how it relates to the styling?

Comment: "They must have some kind of default formatting that is overriding mine." That is correct. There is default column/header formatting in Pandas that overrides row/column formatting applied through the XlsxWriter interface. As far as I know there isn't any public api to change that formatting (apart from the `datetime_format` and `date_format`).

Comment: @ASGM Updated the code to include where I write the data

Comment: Great - can you post the error as well?

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

export = "files/sharepointExtract.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(export)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('files/new_report-{}.xlsx'.format(date.today()), engine ='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1 , startcol=0, header=False, index=False, encoding='utf8')  

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Code to make the header red background with white text
colour_format = workbook.add_format()
colour_format.set_bg_color('#640000')
colour_format.set_font_color('white')

# Code to make the body blue    
table_body_format = workbook.add_format()
table_body_format.set_bg_color('blue')

# Set the header (row 0) to height 15 using colour_format
worksheet.set_row(0, 15, colour_format)
# Set the default format for other rows
worksheet.set_column('A:Z', 15, table_body_format)

# Write the header manually
for colx, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(0, colx, value)
  
writer.save()
```

When Pandas is used to write the header, it uses its own format style which overwrites the underlying xlsxwriter version. The simplest approach is to stop it from writing the header and get it to write the rest of the data from row `1` onwards (not `0`). This avoids the formatting from being altered. You can then easily write your own header using the column values from the dataframe.

Comment: I see you are advising to use both set_row as well as set_column to add formats. Doesn't set_column overwrite the format of the set_row command?

Comment: `set_column()` is used to give default formatting. The `set_row()` used for the header overrides the defaults. Hope this helps.